# scaffolding when using DI for connection strings

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-keyvault, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have [an application written in Core 2.0, using EF Core](https://github.com/radpin/MonoSAR).  I'm using a pattern where:

- [I keep my database connection string in Azure Keyvault](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/how-to-store-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-net-core).
- I use program.cs to read a (.gitignore'd) json file with my Keyvault appid/password, go to the Keyvault, and put my sql connection string into Configuration.
- DI handles everything from there.

My problem is that when doing scaffolding (create a view from a model, even one that doesn't have anything to do with EF models, or creating a controller from a model), Startup.cs/Program.cs don't seem to run so no DI.

Since there's no connection strings around, I get failures when scaffolding. If I add the connection string into a parameterless constructor on my data context class, it works. I can take it back out before I commit my code, but it seems really dangerous.

In short:

**Using the DI method of adding db configuration strings (and not having them written into your application) how do you get scaffolding to work?**

Edit, some code. This is what normally runs in my application, but (I think?) because DI doesn't run during scaffolding then this constructor doesn't get called.

```
public monosarsqlContext(IConfiguration config)
{
    this.m_sqlConnectioNString = config["sqlconnectionstring"];
}
```

To get scaffolding to work, I'm currently needing to copy/paste the connection string into this parameterless constructor. Again, it works, but I'm a fat-finger commit away from pushing my database connection string into a public github repo.

```
public monosarsqlContext()
{

    this.m_sqlConnectioNString = 
    "Server=mycooldatabase.domain.com;Database=soradcool; 
    Persist Security Info=False;User ID=coolguy;Password=coolpassword";

    //only here for scaffolding, do not use
    throw new NotImplementedException("DBContext only used for 
    scaffolding, 
    make use of DI method.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could try to modify the `OnConfiguring` method under your [monosarsqlContext.cs](https://github.com/radpin/MonoSAR/blob/7a47b3c5f7f01613d9ab58386caf1aeb90ee5d05/MonoSAR/Models/DB/monosarsqlContext.cs) to manually retrieve the related settings when you handle scaffolding Controller as follows:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sqlConnectioNString))
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("azurekeyvault.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var config = configurationBuilder.Build();

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                $"https://{config["azureKeyVault:vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                config["azureKeyVault:clientId"],
                config["azureKeyVault:clientSecret"]
            );

            config= configurationBuilder.Build();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("sqlconnectionstring"));
        }
        else
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.m_sqlConnectioNString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested with connection string from `appsettings.json` under the `OnConfiguring` method. For the AddAzureKeyVault part, you need to check whether you could read via `config["sqlconnectionstring"]` or `config.GetConnectionString("sqlconnectionstring")`.